# How To Fix A Redirect Chain

Tags: redirect, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I hope someone might be able to help with this.

My site crawl is showing that I have a redirect chain on my home page. Basically it shows I am going from :

`http:` > `https:` > `https://www.`

I need everything to go from `http://` and `http://www` directly to `https://www.` without the chain.

Below is a copy of the `.htaccess`, can anyone see if there is an error in there that could be causing it.

```
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

In addition, I have seen that they have a plugin called

SSL insecure content fixer installed.

It is showing this under its status:

```
Array (
[HTTPS] => on
[PHPHANDLER] => /usr/local/php70/bin/php
[HTTP_X_REAL_IP] => 109.158.20.158
[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO] => https
)
```

I think possibly this might have something to do with the issue, any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any details on how the example.com -> www.example.com redirect happens, can you describe how that's implemented?

Comment: to be honest the whole thing is confusing me. aside from the standard wordpress settings and the htaccess, i cannot see how most of the redirects are happening. The  SSL is installed via siteground letsencrypt. but it does have https enforce and rewrite external links

Comment: So it could be your WP installation redirecting to `www` or even siteground doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-www to www redirect is most certainly being handled (later) by WordPress. Your existing redirect in `.htaccess` is HTTP to HTTPS only, on the same host - which is actually the preferred (read: necessary) way if you have any plans to implement [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) in the near future. So, this is not necessarily an "error".

However, to avoid the double redirect, you can incorporate the non-www to www redirect into your existing `.htaccess` rule. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If you particularly want a generic (any domain) solution, without hardcoding the domain, then you could do something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Where `%1` is a backreference to the host name (less any `www.` prefix) in the last matched *CondPattern*. Note, however, that without further modification this "generic" solution will also redirect subdomains.